# makefile compile with -g and -O0 automatically

Tags: c

Now I got a makefile like this:

```
#--------------------------------------------------------
#  Choose  a  compiler  
#-------------------------------------------------------- 
CC = gcc

#--------------------------------------------------------
#  Set  your  source  file  and  your  target  executable    
#--------------------------------------------------------
SRC = main.c
TARGET = main2

all: $(TARGET)

#--------------------------------------------------------
#  Compile  the  program    
#--------------------------------------------------------
$(TARGET): $(SRC)
    $(CC)  -o  $@  $(SRC)  

#--------------------------------------------------------
#  Clean  up  (remove  the  executable)  
#--------------------------------------------------------
clean:
    rm  -f  $(TARGET)
```

How can I modify my Makefile so that it compiles with -g and -O0  (that's oh-zero) options automatically? I am really confused with the makefile stuff.

Comment: One way is to change the CC line to `CC = gcc -g -O0`.   But it's more normal to introduce another variable `CFLAGS` which you can figure out by looking at how `$(CC)` is used.

Comment: So I add CFLAGS = gcc -g -O0, and then add $(TARGET): $(SRC)
          $(CFLAGS)  -o  $@  $(SRC).  Is this correct?

Comment: The compilation line would be `$(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(SRC)`.

Comment: Don't put `gcc` in `CFLAGS`. It's additional to CC, not a replacement

Answer (score 2):

Add `CFLAGS=-g -O0` below CC
and change the line 
`$(CC) -o @ (SRC)`

into
`$(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(SRC)`

This would produce a final Makefile that looks like:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -O0

SRC = main.c
TARGET = main2

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(SRC)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(SRC)  

clean:
    rm  -f  $(TARGET)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a very simple (if we define simple by very few lines of code), then all I ask is that you rename your source file to `main.c` instead of `main2.c`.

```
CFLAGS = -g -O0    
all: main
```

Which we can run:

```
$ cat Makefile 
CFLAGS = -g -O0    
all: main

$ cat main.c
int main() {}

$ make
gcc -g -O0    main.c   -o main
```